# Raspberry Pi Wine Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, pi-5, wine

I downloaded Wine on my Raspberry Pi 5. I want to run Java, because I want to run Age of History 2 (the exe file uses Java).

Comment: And your question / problem is?

Comment: Can you run anything? Wine is basically a VM, not an interpreter, so I doubt it is able to run X86 apps on arm.